# How to get actual source IP address on Application Pod using HAproxy as Ingress

Tags: haproxy-ingress

We have deployed haproxy as ingress on our Kubernetes Cluster in remote DC.
Our use case is to get actual source IP (Client IP) on application pod which is php 7.2 based and running in httpd. But we are receiving IP of ingress which is 193.168.100.15 (Although it is Public IP but being used as private network) in our Kubernetes.

193.168.100.15Unauthorized access.
It should be 203.99.50.227 as IP of our NAT device.

On Ingress I am using following annotations.

```
annotations:
    haproxy.org/cors-allow-origin: "*"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    haproxy.org/forwarded-for: "true"
```

and in app servcie yaml file I am using following annotation.

```
annotations:
    haproxy.org/forwarded-for: "true"
```

Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `service.spec.externalTrafficPolicy` to `local`. This is probably dependent on the provider, but it appears to work for [GKE](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/#source-ip-for-services-with-type-loadbalancer) and [AKS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/load-balancer-standard#maintain-the-clients-ip-on-inbound-connections).